# Take into consideration

Tags: grammar, meaning

The following subject is about wells turbine. Entropy generation parameter help to us for designing and provide designers with useful information about the causes of the flow [irreversibilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreversible_process)(entropy generation).
the flow goes through the turbine and contacts with the blade of turbine. these are made that entropy is generated around the blade.

Now, I had a question. Is the bold sentence correct grammatically?

Also, entropy generation factors around the blade are investigated. All of these factors are detected by viscous entropy generation distributions, which record a substantial increase of the viscous component of local entropy generation rate equation. **Any entropy generation analysis improvement on [Wells turbine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wells_turbine) must take these factors into consideration.**

Thanks,

Best.

Ali

Comment: "...on **a** Wells turbine**...".

Comment: or "... on ***the*** Wells turbine"  Interestingly, that sentence is closer to being right than any other in the whole post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this sentence is correct. "Take into consideration" means to "consider" or "take into account".

> [**Take into consideration**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take+into+consideration), to take into account; consider:
>   (ex) We failed to take into consideration the large number of tourists attending the exhibition.